# Could not upload cookbook to opensource chef server

Tags: chef-infra

I am using open source chef server. I configured it in my own virtual machine centos6.5(final)
Then I created certificate using openssl.
I set up workstation.
when performing client list it list out client available in server. But uploading cookbook not working.

```
# knife cookbook upload site
Uploading site     [0.1.0]
ERROR: The data in your request was invalid
    Response: Cannot update sandbox 000000000000c16af5e676fee376c78e: the following checksums have not been uploaded: 00c5a251130f3917aa4d98eb1b637677, 1b201f8f591b47b692586b7273808298, 24e39404448ff1c46d522d28c255298b, 54f5e3e449384933026cf0d357475f8c, 919855b001514143b2094de8d7a1dcf0, 9c6a3407faac0ec61936ff4ce2cce79b, c19bfb26404c17e7480a0dd35a478828, d04122e17ec8802e6b083637a5ad1878, ff512a660b7c80c5f586e78a81d5d08e, fff0a1bb68ffcaf1d1887c2618860ad
```

Comment: Ho did you create a certificate using openssl? You don't have to create any certificates - you copy the certificates from the chef-server for the first admin user.
You mean `knife client list` works?

Comment: @StephenKing Yes knife client list works. I don't know why the above error occur in case cookbook upload. Can you tell me how to deal with this error.

Comment: `knife cookbook test site`

Comment: Did you managed to fix this issue?

Comment: No i just gone with re installing chef server.